# Low pass filter with gaussian weighting in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I am trying to apply a low pass filter to a signal in the frequency domain, with gaussian weighting/roll off curve.
I got the first version of the for loop from my collegues and I admit that I do not understand it. Why is the sigma definition the way it is with the logarythm? I would just put it the Gauss function as I read it in wikipedia (second version).

Why is the resulting filter characteristic a little offset (by approx. 0.2?) for both versions and why is the result 0 for the second?

the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.fftpack import ifft

data = np.loadtxt("profil.txt")
t = data[:,0]
x = data[:,1]

amplitudes = fft(x)
c = np.abs(amplitudes)
c_norm = 2 * c/len(t)
c[0] /= 2
c_half = c[0:len(amplitudes)//2]
f = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), d = t[len(t)-1]/(len(t)-1))

p_t = np.zeros(len(amplitudes))
sigma = np.sqrt(np.log(0.5)/(-2.))/np.pi/10      #FIRST VERSION
s = 0.7                                           #SECOND VERSION
for i in range(len(c)):
    e = np.exp(-2*np.pi**2*sigma**2*f[i]**2)    #FIRST VERSION
    #e = np.e**(-f[i]**2/2/s**2)/s/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)    #SECOND VERSION
    if e > 0.1:
        #FIRST VERSION
        p_t[i] = np.exp(-2*np.pi**2*sigma**2*f[i]**2)
        p_t[-i] = np.exp(-2 * np.pi ** 2 * sigma ** 2 * f[i] ** 2)
        #SECOND VERSION:
        #p_t[i] = np.e**(-f[i]**2/2/s**2)/s/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) 
        #p_t[-i] = np.e ** (-f[i] ** 2 / 2 / s ** 2)/s/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
    else:
        pass

x_filtered = ifft(amplitudes * p_t)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout = True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 1)
a00 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
a00.plot(t, x,color='blue', label="original")
a00.plot(t,x_filtered, color='red', label="filtered")
a00.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1,1,0), loc="lower left", ncol = 1)
a01 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
a01.plot(f,c, label="amplitudes")
a01.set_ylim([0,1000])
a01.legend()
a03 = a01.twinx()
a03.plot(f, p_t, color='red', label='filter characteristic')
plt.show()
```

thanks in advance for any idea or explanation. The resulting plot (first version):

[image]

second version:

[image]

Comment: that is true, I should have studied your answer before posting this question. I have edited it now, as well as the first one!

Comment: Thanks. I now saw that the right y-Axis is just a bit offset, so it is just a graphical problem. I got a fair result now with the normal Gaussian function and Sigma betwenn 0,7 and 1. What do you mean with non-normalized Gaussian in the fourier domain? Would I have to include the standard deviation and mean of the amplitudes in the function? Unfortunately my statistics-course is a while back...

Comment: You plot the filter characteristic in its own axes, the two axes do not have their origin aligned. They don’t need to, unless you force them to. The data itself is not offset.

Comment: Your second version, `np.e**(-f[i]**2/2/s**2)/s/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)` divides by 2πs, meaning you divide the signal amplitude by this amount.  This is why your signal changes amplitude. This function must have unit value at the origin (for `f[i]==0`).